# Why do I get syntax error in the following code

Tags: python, syntax, numbers, interpolation

This gives an syntax error:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = np.array([-­0.23122875, -­0.11375591, -­0.09760733, -­0.07401004, ­-0.03565704,-­0.02449268,­-0.01411058,0.0018971,-­0.0145346,0.00156783,0.0048691,0.01990767,0.02048657,0.01691803,0.02228818,0.02578349,0.02707902,0.01996198])
x = np.array(range(len(y)))
stepsize = 0.0001
xvals = np.arange(0,13.0001,stepsize)
func = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind = "cubic")
yvals = func(xvals)
plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
plt.plot(x,y, "o")
dif = np.diff(yvals)
for i in range(len(y))
    if i == 0:
        print dif[int(i*1/stepsize)]
    else:
        print dif[int(i*1/stepsize)-1]
```

It gives an syntax error in line 5 like this

> y = np.array([-­0.23122875, -­0.11375591, -­0.09760733, -­0.07401004, ­-0.03565704,-­0.02449268,­-0.01411058,0.0018971,-­0.0145346,0.00156783,0.0048691,0.01990767,0.02048657,0.01691803,0.02228818,0.02578349,0.02707902,0.01996198])
>                      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I just do not know why. When I change some of the values in y, it suddenly does work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that supposed to by Python? Then please edit the tags to include the `python` tag. Also, when asking questions about errors such as your, including the actual error output (in full and unedited) is usually helpful, as well as pointing out where in the code the error(s) occur. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be using a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) on this line:

```
y = np.array([-­0.23122875, -­0.11375591, -­0.09760733, -­0.07401004, ­-0.03565704,-­0.02449268,­-0.01411058,0.0018971,-­0.0145346,0.00156783,0.0048691,0.01990767,0.02048657,0.01691803,0.02228818,0.02578349,0.02707902,0.01996198])
```

You need to switch it to a [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) like this:

```
y = np.array([-0.23122875, -0.11375591, -0.09760733, -0.07401004, -0.03565704,-0.02449268,-0.01411058,0.0018971,-0.0145346,0.00156783,0.0048691,0.01990767,0.02048657,0.01691803,0.02228818,0.02578349,0.02707902,0.01996198])
```

Comment: That wasn't really the syntax error I expected. There are others in the code shown. :)